C++20 deprecation of inter-enum-type arithmetic vs anonymous-enum compile-time constants
Anonymous enums are in common use for defining compile-time-only constants in a compiler-supported fashion (i.e. without resorting to Macros), in C. This is also true for C++ (because even while the use of constexpr is somewhat of an alternative, one can still take the address of a constexpr constant and force it to actually have one at run time).
Now, it seems that in C++20, arithmetic between different enum types has been deprecated, it seems. But - I want to use arithmetic between my named constants, e.g.
enum { BlockSize = /* whatever */; }
enum { Padding = /* whatever */; }

// ...

auto my_addr = base_addr + (BlockSize + Padding) * 10u;

but this gives me a deprecation warning. Now, I suppose I can just suppress that, but - what (if any) would be the appropriate change-of-idiom for this code?
To clarify: I'm asking about an answer which works both in C and C++, or if you will, in the intersection of C++20 with C99 (which is why this question is tagged cross-language and mentions C).

consteval function is an alternative. this would enforce a compile-time only evaluation

what does it matter that you can take the address of a constexpr value? fairly sure changing it is at best a segfault, but definitely UB

@Tidemor Accidentally introduces new symbols and you need to have space allocated for them in the binary

A cast or conversion also works: change (BlockSize + Padding) * 10u to (+BlockSize + Padding) * 10u. https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.iso#diff.expr-2

It's somewhat common that pure C compilers and particularly C static analyzers warn against arithmetic on enumeration constants not belonging to the same enum. So the underlying problem is more of a program design issue - doing stuff like this simply isn't considered good/safe practice in either language.

The super-portable solution is otherwise to use macros.

The solution is to make them constexpr variables (with the bonus benefit that you can more easily and explicitly control the types).
inline constexpr auto BlockSize = /* whatever */;
inline constexpr auto Padding = /* whatever */;

It's true that this means that you might actually need definitions of these variables. That seems unlikely to be a real problem. But if that is something you desperately want to avoid, then you can make them consteval functions (the consteval here is just to avoid stashing function pointers to them):
inline consteval auto BlockSize() { return /* whatever */; }
inline consteval auto Padding() { return /* whatever */; }



The constexpr solution does not work even in C++, because if I take the address of the constexpr variable anywhere - it will take up space in memory. 2. The consteval function solution forces me to change all uses of BlockSize and Padding to invoking a function. 3. I need a cross-language solution, edited to clarify that.


@einpklum If you pass BlockSize or Padding by reference or as a pointer to another function, that cannot be inlined, the compiler has to obviously create an instance of that variable, anyways, whether you use the enum hack or an inline constexpr. Note, that the latest C standard C23 has added constexpr variables. So, with C17/C++21, still use the enum hack and silence the warning, and in the future, with C23/C++23, use constexpr.
